# Task to determine the correctness of a date that is being inputted, num1 is day and num2 is month

Tags: java

I don't understand why but when I input 56 5 it outputs *YES*. Please help and if possible describe the cause of the mistake.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
            int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

            if (num1 <= 31 & num2 == 1 | num2 == 5 | num2 == 3 | num2 == 7 | num2 == 8 | num2 == 10 | num2 == 12) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else if (num1 <= 30 & num2 == 4 | num2 == 6 | num2 == 9 | num2 == 11) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else if (num1 <= 28 & num2 == 2) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("NO");
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 4) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: It’s a matter of the precedence of `&` and `|`. Always use parentheses in expressions that involve both. As an aside, it’s customary to use `&&` and `||`, which I would recommend here too.

Comment: If this is an exercise, it’s a fine exercise. For production code one would use `MonthDay.of(monthNumber, dayOfMonth)` and see is one gets a `DateTimeException`. A difference being that `MonthDay` accepts up to 29 days in February, though (since this happens in leap years). If you need to assume a non-leap year, use for example `dayOfMonth <= Month.of(monthNumber).length(false)`, the `false` indicating whether in a leap year or not.

Comment: This question has been incorrectly close-voted as “Not reproducible or was caused by a typo”. It’s fully reproducible and as far as I can tell not caused by any typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue in your code is with the condition statements and the use of the & and | operators. You should be using && and || for logical AND and logical OR operations, respectively. Try changing it.

You should check the logic of your code, I don't think that's the best way to check dates. Still, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            int num1 = 56;
            int num2 = 5;

            if (num1 <= 31 && (num2 == 1 || num2 == 5 || num2 == 3 || num2 == 7 || num2 == 8 || num2 == 10 || num2 == 12)) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else if (num1 <= 30 && (num2 == 4 || num2 == 6 || num2 == 9 || num2 == 11)) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else if (num1 <= 28 && num2 == 2) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("NO");
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 4) {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to define the correct precedence. The complex condition you need is - `first condition is true AND any one of the next being true`

```
if (num1 <= ??? && (num2 == ??? || num2 == ??? || and so on))
```

Some stuff unrelated to the actual question but still important:

1. Since `num1` is day and `num2` is month, rename the variables with their correct names
2. Consider how to simplify the checks, you can use an array prepopulated with data. Hints - the index will be the month and the value at the index will be the days in this month.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code.

1. The `if` conditions in your code use [bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). You need to change them to *logical* [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).
2. After changing them to logical operators, you need to correctly group them.

Logical operators are binary operators, i.e. they have two operands. Hence, when you compile your code, the operands will be grouped. Take, for example, your first `if` statement:
(Note that I have replaced the bitwise operators with logical operators.)

```java
if (num1 <= 31 && num2 == 1 || num2 == 5 || num2 == 3 || num2 == 7 || num2 == 8 || num2 == 10 || num2 == 12) {
```

Operators are evaluated according to their precedence and `&&` comes before `||` so the first part of the `if` condition to be evaluated will be:

```java
num1 <= 31 && num2 == 1
```

If the value of `num1` is 56, then the result of the above is *false*. That result will be used as the first operand in the next part of the evaluation which will be:

```java
false || num2 == 5
```

If the value of `num2` is 5, then the result of the above is *true*. And since the remainder of the condition contains only `||` operators, evaluation will stop and the whole `if` condition is considered *true* and that's why your code prints YES when you enter 56 for `num1` and 5 for `num2`.

What you want is to group all the `||` operators so that they will be considered as a single operand. Hence the `if` condition should be:

```java
if (num1 <= 31 && (num2 == 1 || num2 == 5 || num2 == 3 || num2 == 7 || num2 == 8 || num2 == 10 || num2 == 12)) {
```

The above `if` can be read as...

> if `num1` is less than or equal to 31 **and** `num2` is one of 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 8 or 10 or 12

I believe this is what you want. So, applying the above to all your code produces the following...

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
            int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
            if (num1 <= 31 && (num2 == 1 || num2 == 5 || num2 == 3 || num2 == 7 || num2 == 8 || num2 == 10 || num2 == 12)) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            }
            else if (num1 <= 30 && (num2 == 4 || num2 == 6 || num2 == 9 || num2 == 11)) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            }
            else if (num1 <= 28 && num2 == 2) {
                System.out.printf("YES");
            }
            else {
                System.out.printf("NO");
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 4) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, since Java 8 and the introduction of the [Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), you can use [static] method [of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#of-int-int-), in class `java.time.MonthDay`, i.e.

```java
try {
    java.time.MonthDay.of(5, 56);
}
catch (java.time.DateTimeException x) {
    // Invalid month or day of month.
}
```

Comment: Though rarely used so, `&` and `|` can be used as logical operators too. Or the code in the question would not have compiled. The difference is that `&` and `|` unconditionally evaluates both sides, whereas `&&` and `||` shortcuts the evaluation where possible, which is usually desired. Another difference is that `&` hasn’t got the same precedence as `&&` and similar for `|`.

Comment: @OleVV I believe that I did **not** say that bitwise operators cannot be used. I stated that, in order to get the expected result, the OP needs to change the bitwise operators to logical operators. The OP also asked to explain the cause of the mistake in his code - which I did and which I did not see in the other answers. My answer also includes part of your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321601/task-to-dertemine-the-correctness-of-a-date-that-is-being-inputted-num1-is-day#comment136316916_77321601) (which you wrote after I answered).

Comment: Granted, I see that there’s some confusion about the meaning of *bitwise operator* and whether the OP was using such. In any case, they *need* not necessarily change their operators to obtain their desired result. The operators they use give the result they expect if only they group them correctly, as you also said. Changing the operators is just a *recommendation* that you and I agree about.